# How to achieve 'FrameLayout' component in React Native?

Tags: android, layout, react-native

I know there is a 'View' component in React Native that acts like Android VieGroup, how ever it is more likely to work as LinearLayout - childrens are  arranged in rows or columns.

I am wondering how to achieve 'FrameLayout' behavior - childrens are stacked in the layout, and each child can be assigned an unique gravity location.

For example:
Put 5 childs into a component, each one of 4 childs are aligned to each corner of the layout, and the last child are aligned to center of the layout.

How to write React Native 'render' function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That can be done using position: 'absolute' and align it top,left,right,bottom properties. Here is an working sample

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.topLeft}> Top-Left</Text>
                <Text style={styles.topRight}> Top-Right</Text>
        <Text>Center</Text>
        <Text style={styles.bottomLeft}> Bottom-Left</Text>
        <Text style={styles.bottomRight}> Bottom-Right</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    marginTop: 24
  },
  topLeft:{
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  },
    topRight:{
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 0
  },
    bottomLeft:{
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0
  },
    bottomRight:{
    position: 'absolute',
     right: 0,
    bottom: 0
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Also on rnplay, https://rnplay.org/apps/n6JJHg

Comment: wow, that's awesome! I guess I'm a little careless when I was reading React Native's official flexbox documents. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do overlay this way
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Animated, View, StyleSheet, Easing, Text } from "react-native";

```
class A extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  handleAnimation = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      easing: Easing.ease
    }).start();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.layer1} />
        <View style={styles.overLay}>
          <Text>This is an overlay area</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  layer1: {
    height:100,
    backgroundColor: "lightgreen",

  },
  overLay: {
    height: 100,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "#00000070",
    position: "absolute",

  }
});

export default A;
```