# How to place FAB out of Scrollview tag?

Tags: android, react-native

I am using a FAB in a react native project which is inside of the ScrollView Layout. As expected, FAB is at the end of the ScrollView.

How do I place it at top of ScrollView always?

Below is the activity code -

```
render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent:'center' }}>

            <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: '#EBEDEF'}]}>
            {
             .
             .
             .
             .
             .
             .
             .
             <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

              <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} onPress={() => this.openDialog(true)} style={styles.TouchableOpacityStyle} >

                <Image source={require('../assets/share.png')} 

                       style={styles.FloatingButtonStyle} /> 

              </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
       </ScrollView>
    )
    }
}
```

When I tried to place it after ScrollView tag, I am getting the following error :

```
Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (828:3)
  826 |             </ScrollView>
  827 | 
> 828 |             <View>
```

Comment: hope this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406960/how-to-achieve-famelayout-component-in-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use absolute positioning on the view which wraps your button