# How to layer views on top of each other in React Native to achieve the same effect as a FrameLayout in Native Android

Tags: react-native

[[Possible Duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406960/how-to-achieve-framelayout-component-in-react-native)

I am trying to put views one on top of the other and using native Android dev i would achieve this using a Frame Layout, for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#b1945c"
    />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ccd1cc"
    android:layout_margin="50dp"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Which would look like this:
[image]

How can i achieve the same effect in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
  <View style={{
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor:"#b1945c"
       }}>     
  <View 
    style={{
      margin:50,
      backgroundColor:"#ccd1cc"
         }}>
  </View>
 </View>
```

Comment: There is no reason to make the inside View absolute. The entire render method could simply be defined as
`<View style={{ backgroundColor: "#b1945c" }}>
  <View 
    style={{ margin: 50 }}/>
</View>`